# Behavior of waitpid() in multiple threads?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, waitpid

C++ under Linux (CentOS 6.3), using pthreads. gcc 4.7.

I am now maintaining a program where the primary thread does a blocking call to waitpid(-1,...) to reap any and all possible children.

In a thread spawned earlier from the main thread, I have code that does a fork()/execve() call with a waitpid(childpid,...) after the fork (the moral equivalent of system()).

I'm seeing VERY infrequent instances where the child thread's waitpid call just blocks forever.

Am I correct in assuming that there's a race condition if both of these waitpid calls are blocked and the child exits?

Comment: To head off some of the commentary: No one DESIGNED this app this way. The fork/exec/waitpid calls were added later by people who appear to have been unaware of the main thread's waitpid call.

Comment: You cannot wait for a grandchild.

Comment: @n.m. - no one is trying to wait for a grandchild.

Comment: There would be a race condition. At some point in time the child process must transition from zombie to reaped. However, since you're only waiting for a specific PID in the main thread..

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I thought you are forking a grandchild from a child *process* and not from a child thread. You are definitely having a race here.